# How to set an Ansible API tqm.run() timeout for MFA Users?

Tags: python, ansible, multi-factor-authentication, ansible-api

When 'ansible_user' is mistakenly set to an MFA user, tqm hangs indefinitely.
I set a break point in 'task_queue_manager.py' here:

```
play_return = strategy.run(iterator, play_context)
```

But I can't find anything I can use to stop, end, or error out the process.
Below is sudo code representing a guess to how it could work.

```
timeout = 300
result = tqm.run(play)
if not result and timeout and tqm is not None:
    tqm.cleanup()
```

Does anyone know of a solution directly using tqm or even a workaround like what I've eluded to above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way around this by using the func_timeout lib.  wrapping the tqm.run in a try block and sending it into the timeout fcn worked for me.

`try:
                    exitstatus = func_timeout(self.tqm_timeout, tqm.run, args=(play,))
                except FunctionTimedOut:
                    msg = "tqm.run could not complete within {} seconds and was terminated.".format(self.tqm_timeout)
                    raise Exception(msg)
                except Exception as e:
                    raise Exception('exception in tqm was {}'.format(e))`